# Best way to debug third-party gems in ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, ide

Since there may be a lot of **Ghost Methods** inside a ruby gem, I don't think it is a good idea to study  the inner mechanism of a ruby gem  just  by reading its source code statically. Is there a way to attach the source file of a third-part gem to a running ruby process for debugging so that I can set break point and see how things work dynamically ?
BTW,I've tried to navigate to the source file of a third-part gem in RubyMine by clicking on the context menu "Go To->Implementations" of the 'require' statement or other symbol of  an third-part gem( `require 'watir'` for example ), without success. Is it normal for an IDE of a dynamic typing language such as Ruby to fail a symbol navigation?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I would love to know if there's a better way to do this, but how I usually do it is:

1. Add the ruby-debug gem to your Gemfile (or ruby-debug19 if you're on Ruby 1.9.2)
2. Find the Gem by doing `bundle show gemname`. I'm on a Mac so I usually pipe this to pbcopy so it gets copied to my clipboard. `bundle show rails | pbcopy`
3. Open the gem directory in your favorite editor. `mvim /path/to/gem/directory`
4. Navigate to the file and line where you want to put the breakpoint* and insert `debugger` above the line in question.
5. Reload page, run test, or do whatever you would to get the Gem file to execute
6. When execution stops at debugger, you can inspect variables (`p variable_name`), and move line by line with the [ruby debugger commands](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html#Command-Index).

*Knowing where to put the breakpoint can take some understanding of the code, but you should start in lib/gemname.rb

Comment: Thanks. This works great. FWIW, I used these instructions with [Pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry) instead of ruby-debug and that worked also.

Comment: Would this interrupt other applications on the same machine if they are using the same Gem?

Comment: @flyingL123, I suppose it will interrupt others, if they run in debug mode as your app.

Comment: You can combine steps 2 and 3 by simply calling `bundle open rails` as long as you are exporting your editor. Ensure you have `export EDITOR='subl -w'` (or whatever editor you are using) in your .bash_profile.

Comment: Pro tip - use `bundle pristine` to restore all gems to their cached pristine condition when you are done.

Comment: Instead of restoring all gems, you can pass the gem and only restore that one. `bundle pristine gemname`

Answer (score 16):

I would avoid editing the Gem files as suggested in the currently accepted answer.  Instead, put the `debugger` command in one of your app files and use the `break` command to set a breakpoint in the gem.  I'm using `rvm` with a `gemset` so here is how I do it:

`break /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@<gemset>/gems/<gem_name>-<gem-version>/<path_to_file>:<line_number>`

Comment: Would the accepted answer interfere with other applications on the same machine if they are using the same Gem? If so, it seems like this solution would avoid that problem.

Comment: Yes.  That's the whole point.  Unless you are out of options, I would avoid editing the Gem files at all cost unless you are willing to fork them

Answer (score 4):

Both commands output a path to the gem source in your computer.

```
# if it is present in your gemfile
bundle show gemname

# if not in your gemfile
gem which gemname
```

Then just open the folder in your text editor of choice, and good debugging!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using visual studio code, and you have [normal debugging enabled for rails](https://lankydan.dev/2017/05/12/debugging-a-rails-server-in-visual-studio-code) you can just open the gem file you want to debug in VS Code, example:

```
C:\Ruby26-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\devise-4.7.3\app\controllers\devise\registrations_controller.rb
```

and set a breakpoint with VSCode. It will stop execution on that line.

Answer (score 0):

In languages that change the code at runtime, like Ruby, it is hard to accurately predict 100% the origins of symbols, methods etc.

I deal with a lot of third party gems that need source code analysis and I found that the best tool for this task is [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) + its [Ruby and Rails plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails).

- allows good navigation in the dependent gems source code (unlike other alternatives)
- visual breakpoints and debugging that actually work (with trace and all) **

** it has some glitches with method calls in yielded code blocks (like `each {}`) but I learned to deal with those.

What I usually do is set breakpoints and analyse the code at runtime.