# Debugging Ruby gems

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems

We have a rails application and we are using RubyMine IDE.We need to have a gem project that our rails application will use.What is the best way to debug the gem project in RubyMine.

Can we attach the gem project with our rails application as we do it in .NET?

Can you please provide me the basic architecture that industry follows while dealing with rails application and referenced gem project in RubyMine environment.

Comment: Did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545553/best-way-to-debug-third-party-gems-in-ruby ?