# Reverse engineering how Gitlab uses Devise for PBKDF2 tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, gitlab, pbkdf2

I'm trying to figure out the steps performed by [Gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq), a Ruby on Rails application, to arrive at the authentication token they use.

My knowledge of ruby is basic, and I don't know Ruby on Rails.  From what I have figured out, starting with their [user.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-8-stable/app/models/user.rb) model, Gitlab uses a module called [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to generate the authentication token.  Looking at the Devise  [token_generator.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2/lib/devise/token_generator.rb) module, it seems that the default is a PBKDF2 SHA1 hash with a SHA256 digest, but I also don't know how the [configuration file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/initializers/devise.rb) is processed.

The [`KeyGenerator`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2/lib/devise/token_generator.rb#L38) class is self contained and I am able to duplicate it in another language. But the [`TokenGenerator`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2/lib/devise/token_generator.rb#L7) class is going to take me a while to figure out without learning some Ruby on Rails:

```
  class TokenGenerator
    def initialize(key_generator, digest="SHA256")
      @key_generator = key_generator
      @digest = digest
    end

    def digest(klass, column, value)
      value.present? && OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(@digest, key_for(column), value.to_s)
    end

    def generate(klass, column)
      key = key_for(column)

      loop do
        raw = Devise.friendly_token
        enc = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(@digest, key, raw)
        break [raw, enc] unless klass.to_adapter.find_first({ column => enc })
      end
    end

    private

    def key_for(column)
      @key_generator.generate_key("Devise #{column}")
    end
  end
```

I realize I'm being lazy and impatient, but I was hoping somebody familiar with Gitlab and Ruby on Rails could help me find out:

1. Where in this rails app does `TokenGenerator.generate` get called
   for the user creation, and what are the default `klass` and `column`
   values being passed to it?
2. Where is `"Devise #{column}"` read from, and what is its default value?

In other words, I would like to know what parameters supplied by the users end up as factors to this authentication token.  The plain text password? The encrypted password?  Just a random value?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer but a tip to get there. You can try to inspect the state of those methods when they get called using debugger or pry. Here is how to do that in a gem you don't own.  [Best way to debug third-party gems in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545553/best-way-to-debug-third-party-gems-in-ruby)