# how to debug rails while depending on gems in bundle_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, bundler

I would like to debug the source of 3rd party gems, as per [Best way to debug third-party gems in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545553/best-way-to-debug-third-party-gems-in-ruby)

However I would rather have the gems that I am debugging within the application directory rather than globally installed. It will be easier to navigate and put breakpoint on those files from within my IDE, VsCode.

I managed to install the gems to BUNDLE_PATH within the workspace easily enough by using `bundle config path 'vendor/bundle' --local`

I can also run rails against these gems using `bundle exec rails server` ( I know it's not recommended due to bundle being loaded multiple times, but for my purposes the performance hit is negligible and I'm not sure how else to point rails to vendor/bundle)

In vs code I can debug rails when it's running against the gems in GEM_HOME using:

```
        {
            "name": "Rails server",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
            "args": [
                "server"
            ]
        }
```

However when I invoke rails through the bundler eg:

```
   {
        "name": "Bundled rails server",
        "type": "Ruby",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/bundle",
        "args": [
            "exec",
            "rails",
            "server"
        ],
        "stopOnEntry": true
    }
```

It can't get past the first step of `require "rubygems"`

Any ideas welcome!